# Seemingly unhandled exception in a generator with threads involved

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, generator

Consider the code below.

The intention is to have a generator that manages a thread. The thread is responsible for sourcing data, pushing onto a fifo of size one, which the generator pops from and yields.

It runs fine normally, printing out an ever increasing integer, interleaved with `close thread set? False`.

Now I would expect the `finally:` block running in the main thread of `foo` to always be called, for example with `ctrl-c`, in which case `close_thread` would be set and the thread would exit.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to happen reliably, a reasonable proportion of time when interrupting with `ctrl-c`, the main thread stops but the acquirer thread continues (printing out `close thread set? False` until I kill it). I wonder if the exception is not passed through to the generator in the wrapper object.

Have I missed something obvious?

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from collections import deque
from time import sleep

def foo():

    # As used, deque is thread safe
    processing_fifo = deque([], maxlen=1)
    close_thread = Event()
    close_thread.clear()

    def acquirer():
        a = 0

        try:
            while True:
                processing_fifo.append(a)
                a += 1

                print 'close thread set?', close_thread.is_set()                
                if close_thread.is_set():
                    break

                sleep(1e-6)

        finally: # Make sure we capture any exceptions in the thread
            close_thread.set()

    try:
        acquirer_thread = Thread(target=acquirer)
        acquirer_thread.start()

        while True:
            try:
                yield processing_fifo.popleft()

            except IndexError:
                if close_thread.is_set():
                    break

            sleep(1e-6)

    finally:
        close_thread.set()
        acquirer_thread.join()


class Bleh(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.gen = foo()

    def eep(self):

        return self.gen.next()

obj = Bleh()

while True:
    print obj.eep()
```

**Edit**
It seems sufficient to make the thread a daemon thread (`acquirer_thread.daemon = True`). In that case, the `finally:` block inside the child thread is executed reliably. This doesn't really get me any closer to understanding the issue though.

Comment: Yes, the right way to kill child threads when the main process exists is by setting them to daemons. But remember, daemon threads cannot be joined, so you can drop the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes the `KeyboardInterrupt` occurs when the main thread is not inside of the call to `obj.eep`. In Python, signals (like the SIGINT raised when you do a Ctrl+C) [are only delivered to the main thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html):

> [O]nly the main thread can set a new signal handler, and the main thread
>   will be the only one to receive signals (this is enforced by the
>   Python signal module, even if the underlying thread implementation
>   supports sending signals to individual threads)

If the SIGINT occurs outside of `obj.eep`, no exception handling happens, so your event object never gets set. You can make it happen more consistently if you add a short sleep after every call to `obj.eep()`.

If you make your event object global, and add a `try`/`finally` around `while True: obj.eep()`, the problem goes away:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from collections import deque
from time import sleep

def foo():
    # As used, deque is thread safe
    processing_fifo = deque([], maxlen=1)
    #close_thread = Event()
    close_thread.clear()

    def acquirer():
        a = 0

        try:
            while True:
                processing_fifo.append(a)
                a += 1

                print 'close thread set?', close_thread.is_set()                
                if close_thread.is_set():
                    break

                sleep(1e-6)

        finally: # Make sure we capture any exceptions in the thread
            close_thread.set()

    try:
        acquirer_thread = Thread(target=acquirer)
        acquirer_thread.start()

        while True:
            try:
                yield processing_fifo.popleft()

            except IndexError:
                if close_thread.is_set():
                    break

            sleep(1e-6)

    finally:
        close_thread.set()
        acquirer_thread.join()


class Bleh(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.gen = foo()

    def eep(self):

        return self.gen.next()

close_thread = Event()
obj = Bleh()

try:
    while True:
        print obj.eep()
finally:
    close_thread.set()
```

Comment: Why is the exception not picked up by the generator? Am I missing something about what i means to have exception handling inside generators? From a cursory study of [pep 325](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0325) my understanding is that the close method should make sure `finally` is called.

Comment: @HenryGomersall If the Ctrl+C occurs while the main thread is inside of the generator, it will be always be caught by the `try`/`finally`; that's why Ctrl+C sometimes works. But if the main thread is outside of the call to the `obj.eep()` (and therefore not inside the generator), then the `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't get caught by anything. Adding the extra `try/`finally` ensures your main thread is always protected.

Comment: but `close` is meant to be called on the generator when the generator object is cleaned up, which should trigger the `finally` clause. Is this just not happening?

Comment: Right, *that's* the crux of it: `obj` is sometimes not deleted, so the generator is not deleted. It is sufficient to put a `del obj` in the same place as your last `finally` in the code above. It's a problem that is shown in various guises when the python interpreter doesn't clean up properly around exit time.

Comment: @HenryGomersall It looks like the generator object isn't cleaned up because the thread object isn't cleaned up - my guess is the Python interpreter tries to wait for running threads to exit before cleaning up left over obejcts, and ends up blocking waiting for the thread to finish, which keeps it from cleaning up the generator object.

Comment: @HenryGomersall A peek at the `threading.py` source seems to confirm that. It says that the interpreter calls a method called `_exitfunc` on the `MainThread` object on interpeter exit. That method iterates over all non-daemon threads and tries to `join()` them.

Comment: Ah, useful - that seems to be important detail (though I can't actually find that myself - do you have a link?). Do you know if it is possible to, say, pass an exception to a child thread through `_exitfunc` (short of patching it). This explains why setting the thread to be a daemon thread works fine - that is not checked inside `_exitfunc`.

Answer (score 0):

When you press `ctrl-c` it interrupts only the main thread, which exits but leaves your Python process running because the threads you spawned keep running - they do not receive the `KeyboardInterrupt`.

For this reason your program will not exit if you don't set your threads to `daemon = true`. [From the documention](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The flag can be set through the daemon property.

In this case, when your threads are set as daemons, they will be forced to exit as well when you `ctrl-c` your program which causes your `except` block to execute.

Although you can set your threads to `daemon=True`, there is another way. Try something like:

```
keep_running = True
def acquirer():
    try:
        while keep_running:
            ...
```

Then in your main thread, where you capture the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception:

```
try:
    ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # thread will see this change on next iteration and exit
    keep_running = False
```